# How to use the value function correctly?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've read some documentation here on how to use the 'VALUE' function in oracle. The documentation that I was reading is here: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0620__Object-Oriented/UsethebuiltinOracledatabaseVALUEfunctiontoselectarowfromanobjecttable.htm 
What am I doing wrong here? The code to recreate my 'use case' is below:

```
create table value_sample 
(
 value_sample_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
 value_sample_date DATE,
 value_sample_tx VARCHAR2(50)
);
---
insert into value_sample(value_sample_id, value_sample_date, value_sample_tx)
                  values(1, sysdate, 'hello');
---
CREATE Or Replace TYPE ValueType AS OBJECT (
 value_sample_id NUMBER,
 value_sample_date DATE,
 value_sample_tx VARCHAR2(50)
);
---
select value(v) from value_sample v;
```

Please let me know if there is any further information that I can provide. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The tutorial is first creating an object type and then a table of that type. You somehow seem to have wrongly combined these two steps.

Comment: As the sample in the link suggests, the table is created from a OBJECT type and you are doing it the normal way. This could be the reason why VALUE() does not work in your case.

Comment: yeah I've created the object type but when i run the last select query i only return 'db.producttype' for some reason. I turned serveroutput on but nothing else changes...

Comment: The `as` keyword should not be part of the above `create table` statement. I had to take that out so I could create the table. Then the `value(v)` expression fails with `ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'V'`, because `value` is expecting an object type, but there isn't one in this example. Voting to close, sorry.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, I've edited my question. the as was a typo, my mistake.

Comment: You need to pass an object into `value()`, not a row from a normal table.

Comment: would you be able to show me the syntax? I've tried select value(ValueType)